# How to eliminate angular2 template tags from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, dom

Here is a fragment of the DOM, generated from angular2 component templates:

```
<wrapper>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div id="page-wrapper" style="min-height: 561px;">
```

As we can see, although the template substitutions happened correctly, the angular tags are simply inserted into the DOM. But this is not, what I want. I won't `<header>` and `<wrapper>` to belong to the DOM, it confuses my CSS things. I would like much better if I would only see a

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="page-wrapper" style="min-height: 561px;">
```

in my DOM inspector. Can I somehow do this?

P.s. Also an *"it is impossible"* is an acceptable answer, of course it looks better if it is detailed.

Comment: Might be you can fix that by update your CSS to use `wrapper` instead of `#wrapper` and `header` instead of `#page-wrapper` in CSS. You can also think of changing name of `header` if that conflicts with CSS rules.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1M9FmT05Q6qpsjgvH1XvCm840yn2eWEg0PMskSQz7k4E/edit?pref=2&pli=1

Comment: @AdnanUmer Right, this is what I will do, but first I would prefer the beautiful solutions.

Comment: @agriboz Thank you the link. But I can't see any relevant in that. Could you point me to the section what you find for the question useful?